# Falla de conexion al servidor

Tags: ftp, filezilla

estoy tratando de subir mis archivos al servidor por Filezilla pero me da un error, ya desactive el firewall y el ativirus y nada.

Estado: Conectando a 185.28.21.147:21...
Estado: Conexión establecida, esperando el mensaje de bienvenida...
Respuesta:  220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Respuesta:  220-You are user number 26 of 250 allowed.
Respuesta:  220-Local time is now 20:51. Server port: 21.
Respuesta:  220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Respuesta:  220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Error:  No se pudo conectar al servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás intentando conectarte sin introducir las credenciales de usuario y contraseña.

Si vas al gestor de sitios y añades un nuevo sitio, selecciona en modo de acceso normal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ya lo has intentado de esta forma y no estás haciendo un intento de conexión anónima, intenta conectarte a través de FTP plano. Desde algunas redes no permiten las conexiones a FTP vía conexión cifrada; de ahí el error de AUTH TLS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si introduzco el usiario y contraseña que me viene en panel FTP del hosting (si a esos te refieres), igual lo intento como me indicas arriba y te informo, gracias...